# Probleme mit der Definition von „Nebensatz“

Tags: terminology

Die Definitionen dafür, was genau ein Nebensatz ist, sind zahlreich, doch kreisen sie alle um denselben Kern:

> Nebensätze sind abhängig.
>
> Nebensätze haben Satzgliedcharakter (oder Gliedteilcharakter) und können durch Pronomen und Adverbien ersetzt werden.

In der Dudengrammatik ist die Definition folgende:

> Ein Nebensatz ist ein Teilsatz, der von einem anderen Teilsatz abhängt, diesem untergeordnet ist.

Im Englischen ist die Definition ganz ähnlich. Ich halte einen Ansatz, der sich auf Abhängigkeiten stützt, für hochgradig misslungen. Am besten lässt sich das am Beispiel von „denn“ und „weil“ zeigen. Beide leiten einen Grund ein.

> Warum hast du meine Pizza gegessen?
>
> Ich habe deine Pizza gegessen, weil ich Hunger hatte.
>
> Ich habe deine Pizza gegessen, denn ich hatte Hunger.

Beide Teilsätze (denn und weil) haben semantisch exakt die gleiche Funktion, aber trotzdem ist der Weil-Satz untergeordnet und der Denn-Satz nicht. Jetzt könnte man argumentieren, dass der Denn-Satz alleine stehen kann. Aber kann er das wirklich?

> Denn ich hatte Hunger.

Dieser Satz ist sowohl semantisch als auch ein Stück weit syntaktisch **nicht** komplett. Er hängt genauso von seinem Vorgänger ab wie der Weil-Satz. Gleiches gilt mehr oder minder für alle Konjunktionen.
Das einzige Argument, was jetzt noch bleibt, ist, dass der Weil-Satz eine Verbletztstruktur hat und deshalb syntaktisch nicht alleine stehen kann, sprich abhängig ist. Darüber kann man diskutieren.

> Warum hatte er meine Pizza gegessen? Weil er Hunger hatte? Weil er mir eins auswischen wollte? Ich weiß es nicht.

Das kann man durchaus so in den Druck geben. 
Aber das dahingestellt – wenn die Wortstellung der **einzige** Grund ist, dann ergibt sich ein Problem, sobald man Deutsch verlässt und in eine Sprache geht, die stellungsmäßig keinen Unterschied macht. Dann gibt es nämlich auf einmal keinen Unterschied mehr zwischen Haupt- und Nebensatz.

Nun meine Fragen:

- Von Englisch her gesehen ist ein Denn-Satz ein Nebensatz. Sollte nicht ein Denn-Satz als Nebensatz eingestuft werden, um eine sprachübergreifende Definition von Haupt- und Nebensatz zu erlauben?
- Auch Sätze mit „aber“ oder „und“ können nicht wirklich alleine stehen. Sie sind inhaltlich auch abhängig. Gibt es eine Definition, die universell funktioniert und den Aspekt der Abhängigkeit ausspart?

Comment: "Aber es gibt doch gar keine UFOs!" -- "Und wenn es doch welche gibt?" Diese Beispiele sind umgangssprachlich, aber meiner Meinung nach nicht falsch. Man kann das "aber" und "und" natürlich weglassen.

Comment: Um den Satz alleine zu stellen, wird die Konjunktion fallen gelassen. *"Ich hatte hunger"* ist ein vollständiger Satz, der keine weitere Definition benötigt. Konjunktionen dienen nur der Verbindung und sind somit nicht als Teil des beigeordneten Satzes zu verstehen.

Comment: @Robert... ja kann man, aber ich verstehe nicht, was du damit sagen willst (als Argument)

Comment: @Vogel612... aus der Logik ergibt sich folgendes: entweder ein denn-Satz ist ein Nebensatz oder ein uneingeleiteter Nebensatz ist ein Hauptsatz. Das Problem ist, dass man in anderen Sprachen, wenn man die Konjunktion weglässt ABSOLUT keinen Unterschied mehr hat zwischen Haupt- und Nebensatz. ZUmindest nicht rein syntaktisch.

Comment: @Emanuel Robert wiederspricht deiner letzten Aussage, dass Sätze mit "aber" oder "und" nicht alleine stehen können.

Comment: @Em1 - Ok, sie können also alleine stehen, wenn man die Konjunktion weg lässt. Schön. Dann gibt es in English keine Nebensätze mehr. "I ate because I was hungry" Ich lasse die Konjunktion weg und zack "I was hungry". Funktioniert ganz wunderbar. Klar kann man in Deutsch sagen, "Nebensatz ist wenn das Verb hinten ist." aber dann hat man erstens eine andere Def. als ALLE anderen und zweitens ist dann "Er sagt, er kommt noch" ein Konstrukt aus zwei Hauptsätzen.

Comment: @Emanuel Strikt genommen ist das letzte Beispiel grammatikalisch falsch, aber darüber haben wir glaub ich schon mal diskutiert. Aber definitiv nein, es ist kein Hauptsatz, sondern immer immer noch ein Nebensatz. Ein Hauptsatz kann es nur sein, wenn du das Komma durch bspw. und ersetzen könntest. Die Konjunktion und Satzstellung macht es nicht zum Nebensatz, sondern seine Abhängigkeit. Die Konjunktion stellt nur die Art der Abhängigkeit dar (und kann manchmal weggelassen werden), den Nutzen der veränderten Wortstellung erkenne ich nicht.

Comment: @Em1... aber dann erklär mir doch bitte mal inwiefern ein denn-Satz anders abhängig ist als ein weil-Satz...

Comment: Is this a question about the German language or about linguistics? ;)

Comment: @CarstenSchultz... jap, du hast Recht. Linguistik :). Gibt es dafür ein Stackexchange?

Comment: @Emanuel: [ja](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/). Allerdings überlege ich, ob ich hier gewisse Aspekte rein aufs Deutsche bezogen aufdröseln kann.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft.. vielleicht sollte ich einfach nur nach "denn" fragen. Und alles was für "denn" funktioniert wird dann auch für den Rest funktionieren, da die Funktion ja immer die gleiche ist (nicht semantisch gemeint)

Comment: @Emanuel Ja, ich glaube, es ist sinnvoll, die Frage auf *denn* zu reduzieren. Die Aussage über *aber* und *und* hat eh die meisten eher verwirrt, als dass sie irgendwie deine Frage bekräftigt hätte. – Es ist ok, die Frage auf *denn* bezogen hier zu stellen, man könnte auch überlegen, sie auf linguistic im allgemeinen zu stellen, müsste dann aber ein paar geschickte Beispiel im Englischen, Spanischen und/oder Französischen finden, um seinen Punkt zu bekräftigen.

Comment: Ich verstehe nicht wie die Gepflogenheiten und Notwendigkeiten anderer Sprachen hier eine Rolle spielen sollen. Wieso sollen Nebensätze international identisch sein?

Comment: @userunknown... müssen nicht, aber sind meiner Ansicht nach. Zumindest in Deutsch Englisch und den Romanischen Sprachen haben sie die gleiche Funktion und generell halte ich Grammatikterminologie nur für sinnvoll, wenn sie denn auch sprachübergreifend einheitlich ist. Sonst kann man seine Sachen auch gleich einfach irgendwie nennen. Die generelle Definition sollte übereinstimmen, und dann kann man ja immer noch abweichendes Verhalten beschreiben.

Answer (score 3):

> Sollte nicht ein denn-Satz als Nebensatz eingestuft werden, um eine sprachübergreifende Definition von Haupt- und Nebensatz zu erlauben?

Du kannst die Konjunktion *denn* als Äquivalent zum Englischen *for* betrachten. *For* leitet nämlich ebenfalls eine Begründung ein, gilt aber auch – genau wie *denn* – als koordinierende Konjunktion.

> We listened eagerly, for he brought news of our families.

Würde man nun also im Deutschen einen mit *denn* eingeleiteten Satz als Nebensatz definieren, müsste man es korrekterweise auch im Englischen.

ABER: Ein Hauptsatz ist ein subordinierender Satz, während ein Nebensatz ein subordinierter Satz ist. Ich habe in einer Korpora-Suche folgenden Satz gefunden:

> Ich sah schnell aus dem Fenster, denn ich wußte nicht genau, ob er lachte, weil ich ein fast dreizehnjähriges Mädchen war, oder weil er sich über die Lautsprechernachricht hinwegtrösten wollte.

Versuch mal *denn* und *weil* hier zu vertauschen. Das geht im ersten Fall noch *(… weil ich nicht genau wusste …),* jedoch scheiterst du daran, das *weil* durch *denn* zu ersetzen.

Warum das so ist, sieht man deutlicher, wenn aus allem einen eigenständigen Satz macht:

> Ich sah schnell aus dem Fenster. Ich wusste (es) nicht genau. Er lachte. Ich war ein fast dreizehnjähriges Mädchen. Er wollte sich über die Lautsprechernachricht hinwegtrösten.

Die Trennung von den ersten beiden Teilen ist OK. Es besteht keine zwingende Abhängigkeit zwischen den Sätzen und beide können als allein stehender Satz fungieren. Der zweite Satz **kann** aber als Begründung für den ersten dienen und daher mit *denn*, *weil* oder *da* eingeleitet werden.
Jede weitere Trennung schlägt aber fehl, weil jeglicher Bezug zum vorherigen Satz verloren geht und dadurch die Sätze zusammenhanglos dastehen. Erstmal braucht der zweite Satz eine Begründung. *Ich wusste nicht genau* ist unvollständig. Das kann man durch Einfügen von *es* beheben, sofern dieses *es* zuvor erwähnt wurde. Dann ist *Er lachte* aber nicht mehr die Begründung für *was ich nicht genau wusste*. Naja, und so weiter und so fort.

Ich denke, mein Punkt ist klar: Der mit *denn* eingeleitete Satz hat keine untergeordnete Funktion. Er steht nicht in einer zwingenden Abhängigkeit zum vorherigen. Er vermittelt eine Begründung, *lebt* aber alleine. *Denn* kann durch *weil* ersetzt werden.
Der mit *weil* eingeleitete Satz ist untergeordnet, hat eine zwingende Abhängigkeit zum vorherigen. Die Aussage kann nicht alleine stehen und daher kann *weil* nicht durch *denn* ersetzt werden.<sup>1</sup>
Fazit: *Denn* ist eine nebengeordnete Konjunktion und *weil* eine untergeordnete.

Die Argumentation für *aber* und *und* wird ähnlich aussehen, diese erspare ich mir hier aber. Zumal es bei *und* eigentlich offensichtlich ist.

---

<sup>1</sup>Anmerkung, bevor es falsch verstanden wird: Der mit *weil* eingeleitete Satz ist nicht untergeordnet und abhängig, weil er mit *weil* eingeleitet wird, sondern nur, weil die semantische Aussage im Kontext abhängig ist, und diese fordert in Folge das *weil*.

Comment: Was ist aber nun in Fällen, wo die beiden austauschbar einen Teilsatz einleiten wie im Pizza-Beispiel? In welchem Fall läge dann Deiner Ansicht nach ein Nebensatz vor?

Comment: Das liegt im Ermessen des Sprechers. Eine flapsige Begründung wird wahrscheinlich mit *denn* eingeleitet, eine ultimative Begründung mit *weil*. Alles andere dazwischen ist willkürlich. Nimmst du *weil*, ist es ein Nebensatz. Aufgrund der schwachen Abhängigkeit kannst du diesen aber in einen Hauptsatz umwandeln. Dann nimmst du *denn*, wobei umgangssprachlich mehr und mehr auch *weil* genommen wird (weil ich hatte Hunger) – standardsprachlich jedoch (noch) falsch. Ein Nebensatz liegt also vor, wenn **du** den Satz unterstellst, abhängig machst und dann wählst du eine entsprechende Konjunktion.

Comment: Nebenbei noch ein weiterer Aspekt zu *denn* und *weil.* Nach einem mit *weil* eingeleiteten Teilsatz kann ich den vorhergehenden Teilsatz weiterführen; mit *denn* geht dies nicht: »Ich stand auf, weil der Wecker klingelte, und ging zur Arbeit.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft... sehr interessanter Aspekt :)

Comment: @Em1... Erst mal danke für die Mühe :). In der Antwort sind ein paar gute Gedanken, und das Beispiel ist sehr überzeugend. Den ersten Teil mit "for" könnte man weglassen, da eine Begründnung "Es ist so weil es in English so ist" nicht funktioniert und auch weil "for" und "denn" nicht so 100% deckungsgleich sind. Aber das sei dahingestellt. Dann eine Anmerkung: Auch Nebensätze können subjuntionierend sein - nämlich zum Level 2 Nebensatz.

Comment: Was ich nicht verstehe, ist der ganze Teil nach dem auseinandergenommenen Beispiel. Ja, der Satz "ich wusste nicht genau" ist nicht komplett und funktioniert nur im verbund mit dem anderen (der keine Begründung ist sondern ein Objektsatz) ABER. Alle anderen nachfolgenden Sätze sind total ok. "Ich sah schnell aus dem Fenster" - "Ich wusste es nicht genau" "Ich war ein 13... "- "Er wollte sich über..." die haben ALLE nix miteinander zu tun. Sie sind alle zusammenhangslos. Der mit weil-eingeleitete Satz hat eben NICHT eine zwingende Abhängigkeit.

Comment: Ohne weil ist er einfach nur ein Satz. Mit weil kann er sich theoretisch auf alle zuvorgesagten Teilsätze höheren Levels beziehen... also, deine Beispiel ist super. Es gibt wirklich einen strukturellen Unterschied, aber die Begründung gefällt mir nicht, denn redet wieder über Abhängigkeit. Aber welche? Grammatisch, semantisch? Das kann man immer alles aufhebeln...

Comment: @Emanuel Es ist richtig, dass die Sätze alleinstehend sinnvoll und richtig sind. Aber im Textfluss wirken die Sätze, so wie sie dann stehen, einfach nur wie ein zusammengewürfelter Haufen von Sätzen, ohne jeglichen Zusammenhang. Könnten von einem Geistigverwirrten stammen. Ohne das vorherige korrekte Beispiel, hättest du gar nicht verstanden, was die Sätze wirklich aussagen und was sie miteinander zu tun haben. Es besteht folglich eine kontextuelle Abhängigkeit. Also auf semantischer Ebene. Und diese erfordert es, dass man sie zu Nebensätze macht. Wenn das so klarer ist, würde ich das ändern?!

Comment: @Em1... um ehrlich zu sein nicht, da das auch für den denn-Satz gilt. Ich sehe ohne das "denn" auch da absolut keinen Zusammenhang. "Ich sah aus dem Fenster" "Ich wusste, nicht ob er lachte." Und ich kann dir leicht Beispiele geben, wo es auch ohne Konj./Subj. klar ist. "Ich habe einen Schädel" "Mein Bruder hat gestern Geburtstag gefeiert". Dank Weltwissen, weißt du sofort was los ist.

Comment: @Emanuel Puh. Ich könnte einen Roman schreiben und das Weglassen der Konj. diskutieren. Das ist aber nicht wirklich der Aspekt deiner Frage. Wichtig ist, nicht die Konjunktion macht einen Teilsatz zum Nebensatz, sondern der Fakt, dass es ein Nebensatz ist, erwartet eine bestimmte Art Konj. Welche, hängt davon ab, welche Aussage du treffen willst. "Ich habe einen Schädel, obwohl mein Bruder gestern gefeiert hat und ich als Fahrer nicht trinken durfte." Lasse hier die Konj. weg und merke, dass es etwas verwirrend ist und du erst ganz am Ende die eigentliche Intention erkennst. Konj. helfen ;)

Comment: Nochmal zum Beispiel aus der Antwort. "Ich sah aus dem Fenster" ist eine vollkommen unabhängig Aktion. Sie musst mit allem anderen NICHTS zu tun haben. Ich tue es halt. Weil draußen ein Auto vorbeifuhr. Weil ich die aussicht genieße. Weil ich Spaß dran habe. Alles egal. Ich tu es halt. Der Fakt, dass ich "es" nicht wusste, ist in erster Linie unabhängig davon. Die haben auf den ersten Blick gar nichts mit einander zu tun. Aber gerade weil sie doch abhängig sind, ergänze ich die Konj. um meinen Punkt zu machen. Ich schaue aus dem Fenster, weil/denn ich es nicht wusste. to be continued...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12517/discussion-between-em1-and-emanuel)

Answer (score 3):

Vorweg eine Unterscheidung der beiden relevanten Fälle anhand von Beispielen, damit klar wird, wovon ich rede:

1. **Teilsätze**

   > Ich kam, ich sah, ich siegte.
   >   Ich stand auf und ich ging zur Arbeit.
   >   Ich gehe ins Kino oder ich bleibe zuhause.
   >   Ich bin zwar blind, aber ich bin nicht taub.
   >   Ich esse, denn ich bin hungrig.
   >   Ich bin hungrig, deshalb esse ich.
   >   Der Verdächtige ist schuldig, außerdem ist er vorbestraft.

   In all diesen Fällen kann ich die Position der Sätze nicht verändern, insbesondere kann ich die Teilsätze nicht innerhalb eines anderen Satzes unterbringen.
2. **Nebensätze**

   > Ich esse, weil ich hungrig bin.
   >   Die Sonne ging auf, als ich aus dem Fenster schaute.
   >   Derjenige Verdächtige, der vorbestraft ist, ist schuldig.
   >   Der Verdächtige, der außerdem vorbestraft ist, ist schuldig.

   In all diesen Fällen kann ich die Position der Nebensätze verändern und sie insbesondere in andere Sätze einschieben. Außerdem steht das Verb am Ende.

---

Zäumen wir das Pferd mal von einer anderen Seite auf: Definitionen sind ja kein reiner Selbstzweck. Wozu muss ich überhaupt Nebensätze von Teilsätzen unterscheiden können (alle anderen Fälle dürften kein Problem darstellen)?

**Orthografisch** gibt es keinen Unterschied: Die Rechtschreibregeln nutzen das Wort *Nebensatz* ein paar Male, aber in jedem Fall werden die syntaktischen Eigenschaften von Nebensätzen angesprochen (Verbendstellung, Einschiebbarkeit) und es gibt keinen Fall, in dem Neben- und Teilsätze orthografisch unterschiedlich zu behandeln sind.

**Syntaktisch** unterscheiden sich Nebensätze dadurch, dass sie (meistens) in andere Sätze eingeschoben werden können und in ihnen das Verb am Ende steht. Außerdem kann ich sie in vielen Aspekten wie ein Satzglied behandeln und z. B. Adverbien darauf anwenden.

**Inhaltlich** ermöglichen Nebensätze gewisse Aussagen, die anderenfalls sehr umständlich zu treffen wären, aber keine dieser Eigenschaften gilt universell für alle Nebensätze und wie ich später versuche darzulegen, ist dies eher eine Folge der syntaktischen Eigenschaften als etwas Inhärentes, auf dem man eine Definition aufbauen könnte.

Es ist also in erster Linie wichtig, Neben- und Teilsätze zu unterscheiden, um die richtige Syntax anzuwenden (und die richtige Konjunktion zu nutzen, also z. B. *weil* vs. *denn*). Und genau darauf sollte dann auch eine Definition abzielen, wenn man nicht unnötig mit Ausnahmen jonglieren möchte. Allerdings ist die Definition damit zwangsläufig sprachspezifisch. Zusammenfassend also:

> Die deutsche Syntax erlaubt sogenannte *Nebensätze.* Diese verhalten sich weitgehend wie Satzglieder, werden in der Regel mit gesonderten Konjunktionen eingeleitet, in ihnen steht das Verb am Ende und es gelten noch einige weitere Syntaxregeln.

---

Wie bereits angedroht, sehe ich die ganzen inhaltlichen Möglichkeiten, die Nebensätze eröffnen,¹ als Folge ihrer syntaktischen Eigenschaften an und nicht als inhärent. Am besten deutlich wird dies vielleicht mit restriktiven und explikativen Relativsätzen:

> A) Derjenige Verdächtige, der vorbestraft ist, ist schuldig.
>   B) Der Verdächtige ist schuldig, er ist übrigens vorbestraft.
>   C) Der Verdächtige, der übrigens vorbestraft ist, ist schuldig.
>   D) Der Verdächtige, der vorbestraft ist, ist schuldig.

In Beispiel A ist der Nebensatz unverzichtbar, damit der ganze Satz funktioniert – die gleiche Aussage mit Teilsätzen zu treffen wäre recht schwierig. In Beispiel B liegen zwei Teilsätze vor, die für sich funktionieren, und die Aussage des Satzes ändert sich deutlich. Dies hat aber nichts damit zu tun, dass es einmal ein Nebensatz und einmal ein Teilsatz ist, denn auch Beispiel C hat diese Eigenschaften und ist fast bedeutungsgleich mit Beispiel B. Beispiel D schließlich kann je nach Kontext oder Betonung sowohl wie Beispiel A als auch wie Beispiel B oder C gelesen werden – derselbe Nebensatz kann also eine deutlich andere Rolle im Hauptsatz übernehmen. Insbesondere funktioniert Beispiel A nur deswegen, da ich hier den Nebensatz gewissermaßen als Satzglied, nämlich als Adjektiv nutze – mit einem Teilsatz ginge dies nicht.

Ein weiteres Beispiel (das ich em1 verdanke):

> A) Mary hat ihre Prüfungen bestanden, denn sie hatte gut gelernt.
>   B) Mary hat ihre Prüfungen nur bestanden, weil sie gut gelernt hatte.
>   C) Mary hat ihre Prüfungen bestanden, weil sie gut gelernt hatte.

In Beispiel A treffe ich zwei Aussagen: Mary hat 1) ihre Prüfungen bestanden, 2) gut gelernt. Diese Aussagen setze ich mit *denn* in Beziehung zueinander. In Beispiel B treffe ich hingegen eine Aussage, und zwar über den Kausalzusammenhang. Beide Einzeltatsachen können schon vorher bekannt gewesen sein. Auch hier nutze ich den Nebensatz wieder als Satzglied (nämlich als adverbiale Bestimmung des Grundes) und wende ein Adverb *(nur)* auf ihn an, um den Zusammenhang zu spezifizieren. Beispiel C ist wieder mehrdeutig und kann je nach Kontext und Betonung wie Beispiel A oder B eingesetzt werden.

Schließlich mag noch jemand einwenden, dass viele der Sätze, die ich als fast bedeutungsgleich eingestuft habe, eben nur **fast** bedeutungsleich sind. Zum Beispiel unterscheiden sich die beiden folgenden Sätze darin, wie sie einzelne Aspekte betonen:

> Der Verdächtige ist schuldig, er ist übrigens vorbestraft.
>   Der Verdächtige, der übrigens vorbestraft ist, ist schuldig.

Allerdings denke ich, dass dieser Unterschied überhaupt erst durch die Möglichkeit, diesen Sachverhalt auf zweierlei Weise zu schildern, entsteht und damit eine Konsequenz dessen ist, dass uns die deutsche Sprache den Nebensatz als syntaktisches Konstrukt zur Verfügung stellt.

---

¹ Und eventuelle inhaltliche Abhängigkeiten, die sich daraus ergeben.

Comment: "In all diesen Fällen kann ich die Position der Nebensätze verändern und sie insbesondere in andere Sätze einschieben. Außerdem steht das Verb am Ende."... beides stimmt nicht für alle Nebensätze. "Er hat gesagt, er hat keine Lust." Der zweite Teil ist ein Nebensatz, obwohl nicht verschiebbar und v2. "Ich musste unbedingt etwas essen, weshalb ich die Tagung verließ." Satz kann nicht verschoben werden. Gute Gedanken insgesamt aber eine sprachspezifische Definition lehne ich in diesem Fall ab. Der Unterschied ist in allen Sprachen, die ich kenne, gleich... rein funktional gesehen

Comment: @Emanuel: Mit der Verschiebbarkeit hast Du generell recht, aber nicht im ersten Beispiel, in dem auch möglich, wenn auch recht ungewöhlich, ist: »Er habe keine Lust, hat er gesagt.« Was die sprachunabhängige Definition betrifft, habe ich versucht zu erläutern, dass diese keinen Nutzen bietet. Außerdem wird diese vermutlich genausowenig existieren wie eine sprachunabhängige Definition des Akkusativs – außer eventuell, wenn Du alle Teil- und Nebensätze in eine Schublade packst.

Comment: Außerdem mal anders gefragt: Wenn Nebensätze im Deutschen keine gemeinsamen syntaktischen Eigenschaften aufwiesen – also z. B. Kausal-, Konsessiv- und Konsekutivsätze eine jeweils andere Wortstellung hätten und statt Relativsätzen ausschließlich Partizipialkonstruktionen genutzt würden –, wäre dann die Definition eines Oberbegriffs für diese Strukturen noch interessant?

Comment: Ab der 2ten Linie hast du eigentlich genau dieselbe Aussage getroffen, die ich versucht habe Emanuel im Chat zu verklickern. Ich glaube, dir ist aber besser gelungen, es zu erklären. +1 dafür.

Answer (score 0):

"denn" ist keine unterordnende Konjunktion. Deswegen nach "denn" normale Wortstellung. 
Ich meine dieses "denn" ist ein gekürztes "Warum denn?"

Also müßte man eigentlich drei Sätze ansetzten:

1 Ich habe nichts zu essen bestellt.

2 Warum denn?

3 Ich hatte keinen Hunger.

Wir schreiben das schneller in einem Satz, aber Satz drei hat immer noch etwas
von seinem Hauptsatzcharakter.