# Stimmt es, dass in Nebensätzen das Hilfs- oder Modalverb immer an letzter Stelle steht?

Tags: sentence-structure, modal-verb, subordinate-clause

Ich habe beobachtet, dass in Sätzen wie

> Sie hat am Gymnasium weiter Deutsch gelernt, weil ihr Deutsch Spaß gemacht hat.

das Modal- oder Hilfsverb nach dem Hauptverb an letzter Stelle steht. Ist das immer so, oder gibt es Gegenbeispiele?

Comment: Some related questions that might answer your question: http://german.stackexchange.com/q/5724/1224 # http://german.stackexchange.com/q/5525/1224

Comment: [Another related question in German.](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/9726/2594)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es ist *fast* immer so, wie Du es beschreibst.

Es gibt bei canoo.net eine Seite, die sich [der Stellung des Prädikats im Satz widmet](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Wortstellung/Praedikat/index.html?lang=de) (über einen Link in der Kopfzeile ist auch eine englische Version verfügbar). Dort heißt es

> Ein einteiliges Prädikat steht zum Beispiel ... in einem eingeleiteten Nebensatz an letzter Stelle.
> Das finite Verb [eines mehrteiligen Prädikats] steht an der gleichen Stelle wie das Verb eines einteiligen Prädikats.

Wenn ein Hilfs- oder Modalverb vorhanden ist, so ist es in der Regel auch das *finite* (d.h.  das direkt in Person und Numerus bestimmte) Verb und steht somit am Ende.

Es gibt aber (mindestens) zwei Ausnahmen. Die eine entsteht, wenn die [Prädikatgruppe aus mehreren Verbformen besteht](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Wortstellung/Praedikat/index.html?lang=de#Anchor-Ausnahme-35882), wie z.B. in

> Du bist ins Schwimmbad gefahren, *obwohl du uns hättest helfen sollen*.

Hier steht das finite verb (*hättest*) nicht an letzter Stelle.

Die andere Ausnahme ist ein Satzbau, der zwar (noch) nicht als korrekt angesehen wird, aber häufig anzutreffen ist. (Ich erwähne das also nicht als Empfehlung für Dich, sondern damit Du Dich nicht wunderst, wenn du mal darauf triffst!). Er betrifft Nebensätze, die mit der Konjunktion *weil* eingeleitet werden. Diese Konjunktion wird im alltäglichen Sprachgebrauch oft auch benutzt, um nebengeordnete Hauptsätze einzuleiten, in denen das Verb an zweiter Stelle steht (siehe [Warum wird "weil" zur nebenordnenden Konjunktion?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/6339/warum-wird-weil-zur-nebenordnenden-konjunktion)). Jemand könnte Deinen Beispielsatz deshalb auch so formulieren:

> Sie hat am Gymnasium weiter Deutsch gelernt, weil Deutsch hat ihr Spaß gemacht.

Aber wie gesagt: nicht nachmachen!

Comment: Man hört "weil + <Hauptsatz" wirklich immer öfter, allerdings ist es aktuell (und hoffentlich auch weiterhin) falsch. Meiner Meinung nach kann man es gesprochen halbwegs rechtfertigen, in dem man es schreiben würde als: "Sie hat am Gymnasium weiter Deutsch gelernt, weil: Deutsch hat ihr Spaß gemacht."

Comment: Erwähnt werden sollte vielleicht noch, dass das Verb im Nebensatz an erster Stelle stehen kann, wenn der Nebensatz nicht durch eine Konjunktion eingeleitet wird: *Sie hat am Gymnasium weiter Deutsch gelernt, hat Deutsch ihr doch Spaß gemacht.*

Answer (score 1):

In German, subordinate clauses have their predicate on *last position* with the auxiliary verb (haben, sein), if needed, the very last word. *Weil* at the beginning of the clause (after a full stop or a comma, or question mark) makes a clause a subordinate clause, because *weil* denotes a reason which **explains** the main clause.

This also works when the subordinate clause comes in front, so it's not related to the *second* clause:

> Sie hat am Gymnasium weiter Deutsch gelernt, weil ihr Deutsch Spaß gemacht hat.
>
> Weil ihr Deutsch Spaß gemacht hat, hat sie am Gymnasium weiter Deutsch gelernt.

are identical, apart from emphasis. Note the switched *sie hat* -> *hat sie*. That's another rule, when the main clause does not lead a sentence, the predicate comes in front of it instead of second position.

Note the predicate of the main clause isn't *hat* but *hat gelernt* and the predicate of the subordinate clause is not *gemacht hat* but *hat gemacht*. If this is too much for you right now, stick to simple past.

> Sie lernte am Gymnasium weiter Deutsch, weil ihr Deutsch Spaß machte.
>
> Weil ihr Deutsch Spaß machte, lernte sie am Gymnasium weiter Deutsch.

Again, identical apart from emphasis.

Last example:

> Warum lernte sie am Gymnasium weiter Deutsch? – Weil ihr Deutsch Spaß machte!

That one is a bit odd because the second sentence should be a main clause because a bare subordinate clause makes not sense, right? Yes, it's a main clause that *follows the rules of the subordinate clause* because it's an answer to a question starting with *weil*.

Answer (score 0):

I found that about all those conjunction words that link clauses, e.g. dass, obwohl, weil, aber, und, als ob,obgleich, obwohl, damit, sobald,solange, etc. 
If we have an auxiliary-verb or modal-verb, it will come at last position after the main verb in second subordinate clause; For example:

> Ich habe mich geärgert, weil er so spät gekommen ist.*
>   *I was annoyed that he arrived so late.*
>
> Wir wussten nicht, dass er die Arbeit schon gemacht hatte.*
>   *We didn’t know that he had already done the work.*

Comment: Isn't the second part of this sentence missing "I found that about all those conjunction words that link clauses"?